# Can we use index to access element inside ng-repeat like we do in simple array or list like array[2]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I am new to angular.I want to know Can we use index to access element inside ng-repeat like we do in simple array or list like array[2].As I have a list of list .I want to iterate over the outer list and show the value from internal list.
Like
List<List> myList=[[1,2],[3,4]]
I want to do something like follow
[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRHmK.jpg)

Comment: quick answer is yes you can

Comment: But in case of string list. I am only getting the first character

Comment: Perhaps you should do some data mapping in controller then. Or create a custom filter and check type

Comment: If you want additional help you will need to provide a [mcve]